# SQL2 equivalent for this XPath query

Tags: aem, jackrabbit, jcr, jcr-sql2

Is there an `SQL2` query that is identical to the following `XPath` query:

```
/jcr:root/content/ancestor//parent/jcr:content
```

It should return the following nodes, for example:

```
/content/ancestor/a/b/c/parent/jcr:content
/content/ancestor/a/parent/jcr:content
/content/ancestor/parent/jcr:content
```

But not the following nodes:

```
/content/xxx/a/b/c/parent/jcr:content
/content/xxx/a/parent/jcr:content
/content/xxx/parent/jcr:content
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work:

```
SELECT * FROM [nt:base] AS s 
  INNER JOIN [nt:base] AS parent
    ON ISCHILDNODE(s, parent)
WHERE
  ISDESCENDANTNODE(s, [/content/ancestor]) AND
  NAME(parent) = 'parent' AND
  NAME(s) = 'jcr:content'
```

If the type of `s` is `cq:PageContent` and type of `parent` is `cq:Page` you may use this information to make the query faster:

```
SELECT * FROM [cq:PageContent] AS s 
  INNER JOIN [cq:Page] AS parent
    ON ISCHILDNODE(s, parent)
WHERE
  ISDESCENDANTNODE(s, [/content/ancestor]) AND
  NAME(parent) = 'parent' AND
  NAME(s) = 'jcr:content'
```

Comment: do you know why XPATH was deprecated in JCR 2? XPath queries are sometimes much shorter and more readable compared to SQL2 queries.

Comment: Even though it was deprecated, I'm still using XPATH because of this. Internaly they are translated to SQL2 though. 
It is so much easier to map the node structure to XPATH. So I'd also like to know why we should use the way more complex and hard to read SQL2 over XPATH.

Answer (score -2):

you can easily convert xpath to sql2 and vice-verse using "query tool" in crxde [image]

Comment: You can't. The purpose of this dropdown is to define the type of query entered in the *Query* field.